# JUnit 4.11 Repeating TestSuite

Tags: java, junit, test-suite

i'am trying to achieve, that my testsuite will be executed multiple times.
JUnit 4.10 demonstrate it easiely:

I have two testclasses into my suite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ TestClassA.class, TestClassB.class })
public class MyTestSuite {



}
```

But i dont know, how can i determine, that the standard-runner "Suite.class" execute my MyTestSuite multiple times?

Comment: Why would you want to run them multiple times? Don't you trust them enough to work once? Or maybe your tests depend on race conditions or something.

Comment: i want easiely do regression tests :)

Comment: I don't understand. If you run the tests 10 times, you'll get the exact same output 10 times (assuming they're good tests), so it's pointless.

Comment: Please read this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing

You dont know about the issues and goals of my project. Maybe it is necessary, that one test will be rerun more times, to ensure that is still correct.

Comment: I know what regression testing is. But you're supposed to re-run the tests _after_ you've changed something... Running them 10 times in a row isn't regression testing.

Comment: I would re-run tests anyway, when i changed something. My goal was implement unit-test as regression-test